# Haskell: How to adjust load-factor in HashMap in unordered-containers?

Tags: haskell

C++/Java hash maps have load factor parameter for adjusting map performance.

I wasn't able to find a trace of such parameter for HashMap from unordered-containers.
`fromList` takes just a list with data.

Comment: It's not a hash table, it's a HAMT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such parameter exists, so you cannot tweak it. Just because some feature exists in a Java library does not mean that it will exist in an analogue in another language.

Comment: I want Java HashMap  in Haskell